# ZF2: Redis | Change dump.rdb location

Tags: zend-framework2, redis

I have Redis running on my ZF2 project.

Redis by default saves its dump.rdb in the root of my project. How can I change that to save in cache/data?

My RedisFactory.php:

```
    <?php
namespace Application\Service\Factory;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;
use Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\RedisOptions;
use Zend\Cache\Storage\Adapter\Redis;

class RedisFactory implements FactoryInterface {

    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {

        $redisOptions = new RedisOptions ();
        $redisOptions->setServer ( array (
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'timeout' => '30'
        ));

        $redisOptions->setTtl(86400);

        $redisOptions->setLibOptions ( array (
                \Redis::OPT_SERIALIZER => \Redis::SERIALIZER_PHP,
        ) );

        $redis = new Redis ( $redisOptions );

        return $redis;
    }

}
```

And in my module.config.php:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'Application\Cache\Redis' => 'Application\Service\Factory\RedisFactory',
    ),
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
        'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory'
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'translator' => 'MvcTranslator',
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

From `redis.conf` example configuration file:

```
# The working directory.
#
# The DB will be written inside this directory, with the filename specified
# above using the 'dbfilename' configuration directive.
#
# The Append Only File will also be created inside this directory.
#
# Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name. dir ./
```

However if you have a running server, you may also try to use

```
CONFIG SET dir /new/dir
```

And then trigger a BGSAVE and make sure it works <- **important step**

You may use `CONFIG REWRITE` later to consolidate the config in `redis.conf`.

Comment: However this will change the global directory? It seems that I have a dump.rdb in my ~ dir, and for every vhost.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'd like to set it up from the CLI when running redis server,

```bash
redis-server --dir cache/data/
```